# Delete specific lines of characters

Tags: notepad++, regex

i want to delete all lines start with **alter table**........and end with **;** there are several **alter table**........ statement in my file

```
create table EMPLOYEE
(
  EMP_ID   NUMBER not null,
  D_ID NUMBER,
  P_ID     NUMBER,
  EMP_DESC VARCHAR2(2000)
)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );



alter table  CALL_OCCURED
  add unique (HIS_ID)
  using index 
  tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
  );


create table DEPARTMENT
(

  D_ID         NUMBER(11) not null,
  CLI             VARCHAR2(45),
  DNS             VARCHAR2(20),
  ATED_DATE    DATE,
  START_TIME DATE,
  END_TIME   DATE,
  LAT             VARCHAR2(45),
  LON             VARCHAR2(45),
  MSN      VARCHAR2(45),

)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

Comment: You could use a find/replace but it's quicker to just delete the lines you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to delete all lines start with "alter table" and ending with ";"

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `alter table.*?;`
- Set "Replace with" to an empty string
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Enable "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)